# How to detect Collision only once Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made the script bellow to instantiate a floating text when the player collide with a wall, the problem is that several Texts are instantiated because the player collide with the wall and stay in collision for some time before quitting. Is there any way to detect the collision only once?

**The Script:**

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){

    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall")){

        if(WallFloatingText){
            ShowWallFloatingText();
            count = count + 3;
            countText.text = count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `OnCollisionEnter` should only be called the first frame you begin collision, if you are spawning multiple text, then your character is somehow triggering that twice.  Care to show us your movement code?  I am asking because depending on how you are moving the character can cause this behavior

Comment: An example of things that can cause this is directly updating the `transform.position` or using `transform.Translate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating a flag detecting that wall has already been hit.

```
private bool collisonOccured = false;
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){
    if(collisonOccured)
        return;
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall")){
        if(WallFloatingText){
            ShowWallFloatingText();
            count = count + 3;
            countText.text = count.ToString();
            collisonOccured = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to turn off the flag

Comment: Don't forget to add a statement setting back collisionOccured to false when no collision occured

Comment: @Eddge That is what I meant, but I have corrected it to avoid confusion on that.

Comment: @PierreBaret Yes, based on his code provided I was unable to tell him the best place to do this (probably a timer, or have a method that detects OnCollisonExit)

Comment: @JayMason How exactly would he add the flag to the object rather than being in the class? as it being a class variable it would only exist once per object(So it already exists on the object since it is apart of the class)...

Comment: @Eddge You are right. Sorry, that wouldn't work storing it in the collision object.

Comment: You could put all the `if` conditions onto a single line to remove nesting